# Eliminar recuadro de input type "color"

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola amigos, necesito sacar el recuadro del color, es decir que quede el color solo.

Mi código:

```css
input {
    margin: .4rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="color" id="head" name="head"
           value="#e66465">
    <label for="head">Head</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="color" id="body" name="body"
            value="#f6b73c">
    <label for="body">Body</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tenes que modificar el css del `input` `type="color"`.

```css
input[type="color"] {
    appearance: auto;
    width: 44px;
    height: 23px;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
    border-width: 0px;
    border: inherit;
    border-image: initial;
    padding: 0px;
}
input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
}
input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="body" name="body"
        value="#f6b73c">
<label for="body">Body</label>
```